install a switch on machines or switches on machines
If I say

Install a switch on every machine.

I'm sure that people would install two SWs if two machines exist.
But if I say

Install a switch on a machine.

Would they install only one SW even when there are two machines?
Also, just to make sure,

Install a switch on machines

This sentence is wrong. Right? But If I write

Install switches on machines.

People would be confused whether they should install one or more than one SWs on each machine.
Am I right?

Install one switch per machine.

Compare this question, this, and this. It's potentially ambiguous and similar questions often depend on knowing whether more than one per unit makes sense. "Pat the boys on their heads" is unambiguous because each boy has one head. But I don't know how many switches a machine could have.

An instruction to "Install a switch on a machine" invites the question "What machine?" - or "Which machine?" if there were only two of them.

When giving instructions, you want them to be clear. When the hearer can't even make sense of instructions, they might say "Huh?" and ask for an explanation. But instructions that make some sense but are not perfectly clear might cause the hearer to guess at a meaning or make an assumption.

If you want them to install a switch on a pair of machines:

Install a switch on both machines.

If you want them to install a switch on all machines (and there are more than two):

Install a switch on every machine.

Another way is to say:

Install a switch on all n machines.

where n is the number of machines involved in the task:

Install a switch on all six machines.

P.S. A mere plural noun is not grammatical:

Install a switch on machines. No

You must specify the machines with some form of determiner:

Install a switch on these machines.
Install a switch on the machines in the metal shop.

